# UIBlurEffect not working as expected on my UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, uivisualeffectview

I have a `UIView` and I set its frame in my `viewDidLoad`. I then use a `blurBackgroundForView` function to blur it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  view.frame = CGRectMake(0, superView.frame.maxY-height, superView.frame.width, height)
  // The view is supposed to peak in from the bottom 
  AnimationHelper.blurBackgroundForView(view)
}

static func blurBackgroundForView(view: UIView!){
  view.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
  let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
  let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
  blurEffectView.frame = view.frame
  view.insertSubview(blurEffectView, atIndex: 0)
  }
}
```

The issue is that the background of the `UIView` is **NOT** blurred.
When I move the function call of `blurBackgroundView(view)` above the `view.frame = ...`
I get a blurred view, but the blurred view is much to large.

Comment: Try to use:
    `blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds`

Comment: Move the code in your `viewDidLoad` to your `viewDidAppear` perhaps. The code you've provided works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The frame for blurEffectView should be CGRectMake(0, 0, superview.frame.width, height)